# Difference between yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ and yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX?

Tags: java, isodate

Wondering if they represent different formats or are essentially the same (just new vs old presentations).

Comment: look to this reference may be it will help you. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html

Comment: @PawanMaurya the page you linked does not mention 'XXX'

Answer (score 3):

Based on [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) :

> **Offset X and x:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters.
>   -One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'.
>   -Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'.
>   -Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.
>   -Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'.
>   -Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'.
>   -Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException. Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.
>
> **Offset Z:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters.
>   -One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the offset is zero.
>   -Four letters outputs the full form of localized offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero.
>   -Five letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero, with colon. It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero.
>   -Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.

Code :

```
public static void printDate(Temporal t, String format) {
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).format(t));
}

public static void testJavaTime() {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");       //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+0200    
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");      //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+0200    
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ");     //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+0200    
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ");    //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115GMT+02:00
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");   //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+02:00   
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");       //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+02      
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXX");      //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+0200    
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");     //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+02:00   
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXX");    //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+0200    
    printDate(zdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX");   //2019-10-14 08:15:53.115+02:00
}
```

---

Based on [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), this is a simple matter of possible format :

```
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```

No matter the amount of `Z`, it will always use a format `[-+]####`
But with `X`, it is different.

- `X` : `[-+]##`
- `XX`: `[-+]####`
- `XXX`: `[-+]##:##`

Now, let's demonstrated this :

```
public static void printDate(Date d, String format){
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(d));
}

public static void testJavaDate() {
    Date d = new Date();
    printDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");    //2019-10-14 07:52:10.308+0200 
    printDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");   //2019-10-14 07:52:10.308+0200 
    printDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ");  //2019-10-14 07:52:10.308+0200 
    printDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");    //2019-10-14 07:52:10.308+02   
    printDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXX");   //2019-10-14 07:52:10.308+0200 
    printDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");  //2019-10-14 07:52:10.308+02:00   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing us the `SimpleDateFormat`. But I guess the result is different when you use joda time instead?

Comment: @user1589188 you didn't mention JodaTime in your question ;)

Comment: That the kind of information that should have been provided in the question @user1589188 ... no this should not be to much different. Those are defined by ISO standards (mentionned on the documentation pages like [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Yup sorry, I didn't know different tools parse the format string differently. In joda ZZ has colon (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime()). So back to my question, why need both ZZ and XXX to achieve the same (if they are in fact the same in joda)?